# How and why assembleDebug task got moved from "build" to "other tasks" in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Usually in Android studio under `build` we have `assemble`, `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease`. My project had it that way until recently. All of a sudden `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelase` disappeared from `build` and now can be found in `other tasks` (see the picture).

[image]

Running `gradlew` from command line show the same, i.e.:

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assemble main outputs for all the variants.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
bundle - Assemble bundles for all the variants.
classes - Assembles main classes.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
cleanBuildCache - Deletes the build cache directory.
compileDebugAndroidTestSources
compileDebugSources
compileDebugUnitTestSources
compileReleaseSources
compileReleaseUnitTestSources
extractDebugAnnotations - Extracts Android annotations for the debug variant into the archive file
extractReleaseAnnotations - Extracts Android annotations for the release variant into the archive file
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
testClasses - Assembles test classes.
```

I don't think that I've made anything unusual in my gradle files. Does anyone have an idea what might have happened and why `assembleDebug` is not shown in `build` but in `other tasks`?